# remove NaNs if only value already exists in corresponding Ids pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
 Id,ProductId,Product
  1,100,a
  1,100,x
  1,100,NaN
  2,150,NaN
  3,150,NaN
  4,100,a
  4,100,x
  4,100,NaN
```

Here I want to remove some of the rows which contains NaN and some I don't want to remove. 
The removing criteria is as follow.
I want to remove only those NaNs rows whose Id already contains the value in Product columns. 
for example, here Id1 has already value in Product columns and still contains NaN, so I want to remove that row.
But for id2, there exists only NaN in Product column. So I don't want to remove that one. Similarly for Id3 also, there is only NaN values in the Product columns and I want to keep it that one too.

Final Output would be like this

```
Id,ProductId,Product
1,100,a
1,100,x
2,150,NaN
3,150,NaN
4,100,a
4,100,x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont use `groupby` if exist alternative, because slow.

```
vals = df.loc[df['Product'].notnull(), 'Id'].unique()
df = df[~(df['Id'].isin(vals) & df['Product'].isnull())]
print (df)
   Id  ProductId Product
0   1        100       a
1   1        100       x
3   2        150     NaN
4   3        150     NaN
5   4        100       a
6   4        100       x
```

**Explanation**:

First get all `Id` with some non missing values:

```
print (df.loc[df['Product'].notnull(), 'Id'].unique())
[1 4]
```

Then check these groups with missing values:

```
print (df['Id'].isin(vals) & df['Product'].isnull())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Invert boolean mask:

```
print (~(df['Id'].isin(vals) & df['Product'].isnull()))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
dtype: bool
```

And last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[~(df['Id'].isin(vals) & df['Product'].isnull())])
   Id  ProductId Product
0   1        100       a
1   1        100       x
3   2        150     NaN
4   3        150     NaN
5   4        100       a
6   4        100       x
```

Comment: Nice answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can group the dataframe by `Id` and drop the `NaN` if the group has more than one element:

```
>> df.groupby(level='Id', group_keys=False
             ).apply(lambda x: x.dropna() if len(x) > 1 else x)

    ProductId Product
Id                   
1         100       a
1         100       x
2         150     NaN
3         150     NaN
4         100       a
4         100       x
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate groups (`Id`) where values (`Product`) are all null, then remove required rows via Boolean indexing with `loc` accessor:

```
nulls = df.groupby('Id')['Product'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().all())
nulls_idx = nulls[nulls].index

df = df.loc[~(~df['Id'].isin(nulls_idx) & df['Product'].isnull())]

print(df)

   Id  ProductId Product
0   1        100       a
1   1        100       x
3   2        150     NaN
4   3        150     NaN
5   4        100       a
6   4        100       x
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with parameter `count` and then boolean indexing using [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) of `Product` column as:

```
count = df.groupby('Id')['Product'].transform('count')
df = df[~(count.ne(0) & df.Product.isnull())]

print(df)
   Id  ProductId Product
0   1        100       a
1   1        100       x
3   2        150     NaN
4   3        150     NaN
5   4        100       a
6   4        100       x
```

Comment: sorry, `df = pd.concat([df]*1000000)` is really bad for groupby timings, because huge groups, timings are wrong and really bad :( Really dont do it :(

Comment: So you need really timings for yours to show you are wrong? Do you really think OP have only 4 `Id` unique values in real data? Because your timings working only  for it. Sorry, please remove it or create 100, 1000 unique id and timings should be different.